# OpenSSH server rejected connection

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, openssh

In BitBucket I have my SSH key:

[image]

In SourceTree I have:

[image]

When I try to clone I get:

[image]

I did some googling around and came across this post https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html section General SSH troubleshooting and I get

[image]

(please note I am working remote but I have access to all network resources!, it is NOT a VPN issue)

However Vipul, my colleague, who is onsite, can clone repos w/o issue gets the following:

[image]

Which should not work according to the Confulence.Atlassian.com as:

[image]

I then added -v to get the debugger output

[image]
[image]

My collegue who is onsite gets:

[image]

Although it shows Permission denied (publickey) he can actually clone a repo w/o issues.

What should I do so I can clone the repo remotely while on VPN.  (before you ask, yes, I was able to clone a repo onsite partially, but I got an error I ignored so let's assume I can't clone anything)

I called our companies tech support but they verified my VPN connection is valid and works so they too are not sure why I am having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to connect using GitBash so this is my workaround.